# GDB 7.6 TUI does not refresh the display, creating artifacts

Tags: gdb

I'm using GDB 7.6 on a remote server.

When I start `gdb`, everything is fine, as long as the program to debug is not run. I can use up and down arrows to navigate through GDB history, etc. No display bug to report.

When I create a breakpoint somewhere in my program and then `run` the program to debug, the display has many artifacts (characters displayed at the wrong place) until I run `refresh`.
From then on, `next`, `stepi`, `nexti`, up and down arrows, etc. work *but* the display continues to draw characters in wrong places.
If I don't run `refresh` at each step, the display is not what it should be.
Furthermore, when I hit the up or down arrow key, the raw charcodes`^[[A` or `^[[B` are displayed, not allowing to know which history command will be executed.

I tried defining hooks like

```
define hook-nexti
refresh
end
```

This actually refreshes the screen but there can still be unwanted artifacts sometimes (especially on the highlighted line of executed code) and is not an acceptable solution, as I have no need for hooks on my local machine (GDB 7.11, zsh 5.0.2).

I happen to also have a GDB 7.7 on my machine, with which the issue can be reproduced. Is this a bug that has been fixed between GDB 7.7 and GDB 7.11?
If yes, I'll just compile `binutils-gdb` from source since I've no root access on the remote server.